# Insert Date in Outlook Subject line: "Can't find project or library."

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I use this code in Excel 2016 to insert the date into the subject line of an Outlook email.

For a user of Excel 2010 the debugger shows

> "Can't find project or library"

on the word "Date".

What can I change for the earlier version of Excel?

```
myMail.Subject = Range("Q1").Value & " 10-8 Form - " & Format(Date, "dddd - mmmm dd, yyyy")
```

Comment: Weird. Try `VBA.Date`.

Comment: Maybe it is not anything to be changed in the code... Please, check if a reference is missing. On the computer in discussion, being in VBE: Tools - References and see if one of them is displayed as missing.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is a function that's located in the VBA standard library, under the `DateTime` module. Like all standard library functions, it can be accessed without a qualifier because it lives in global scope, so `Date`, `VBA.Date`, and `VBA.DateTime.Date` all do exactly the same thing.

Unless there's a `Date` identifier that's in-scope with a tighter accessibility than *global* - then an unqualified `Date` refers to whatever that in-scope identifier refers to.

But that wouldn't cause a "Can't find project or library" error.

This compile error typically highlights a nonsensical identifier in the standard library. Here `Date`, but often it's a string function like `Left` or `Format`.

The reason is because something is amiss in the program's internal names list, and the compiler is getting very confused. Bring up *Project References* from the *Tools* menu, and look for a referenced library that says "MISSING" - you'll need to remove (and possibly re-add) that reference to fix the problem.

If no reference is missing, export all modules, then re-import them back in. The [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) VBE add-in (I manage this open-source project) has tooling to do this with minimal effort (one-click export everything, then one-click [sync project](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/12/11/sync-project-with-files/) from the file system) - this normally removes all shreds of a corrupted VBA project.